# Proving the following bijection

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics, computer-science

Let $F = \lbrace S_1, S_2, \dots, S_n \rbrace$, where $S_i \subset \lbrace 1, 2, \dots, 3m\rbrace$ and define a function $f: F \to \mathbb{N}$ by
$$
f(S_i) = \sum_{j \in S_i} (n+1)^{3m-j}
$$

then $S_i \sqcup S_j = S \iff f(S_1) + f(S_j) = f(S)$, where $\sqcup$ is disjoint union.

I've already proven that $S_i \sqcup S_j = S \implies f(S_1) + f(S_j) = f(S)$, but I'm not sure how to prove the other direction.

This is not homework. I'm doing preparations for an oral exam and a proof that relies on this was skipped by the course notes.

Comment: Michael what exactly is the set $S$? are you defining it to be the disjoint union of $S_i$ and $S_j$?

Comment: Yes exactly (fill text to reach 15 characters.)

Comment: What if $S_1=\{1\}$ and $S_2=\{2\}$, then $S_1 \cup S_2=\{1,2\}$ and $f(S_1)+f(S_2)=(n+1)^{3m-1}+(n+1)^{3m-2} \neq \{1,2\}$. Perhaps then I don't understand your question so some clarification would be nice. Thanks.

Comment: Oh! Now I see your source of confusion! Fixed my mistake in the question. The implication is supposed to be $S_i \sqcup S_j = S \iff f(S_i) + f(S_j) = f(S)$. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $i \neq j$ and define $T=S_i \cap S_j$. Then we can write
$$f(S_i)=\sum_{k \in S_i-T}(n+1)^{3m-k}+\sum_{k \in T}(n+1)^{3m-k}.$$
Likewise
$$f(S_j)=\sum_{l \in S_j-T}(n+1)^{3m-l}+\sum_{l \in T}(n+1)^{3m-l}.$$
Then
$$f(S_i)+f(S_j)=\sum_{k \in S_i-T}(n+1)^{3m-k}+\sum_{l \in S_j-T}(n+1)^{3m-l}+2\sum_{c \in T}(n+1)^{3m-c}.$$
Let $S=S_i \cup S_j$, then $S=(S_i-T)\cup (S_j-T) \cup T$. Therefore
$$f(S)=\sum_{k \in S_i-T}(n+1)^{3m-k}+\sum_{l \in S_j-T}(n+1)^{3m-l}+\sum_{c \in T}(n+1)^{3m-c}.$$
So for $f(S)=f(S_i)+f(S_j)$, we need to have
$$\sum_{c \in T}(n+1)^{3m-c}=0.$$
Since we are summing positive integers therefore the only way this sum could be zero is when $T=\phi$, in which case $S_i \cap S_j=\phi$ and $S$ would be the disjoint union of $S_i$ and $S_j$.

Comment: Thank you! The idea of $S = (S_i - T) \cup (S_j - T) \cup T$ was the crucial piece I was missing. Elegant proof!